# How to shift elements in array php

Tags: php, arrays, timetable

I´m doing timetable for school. I already have selected data from DB, but all data are represented at the beginning-at 7,10am(pict 1). But some lesson starts at 7,10, others starts at 8am. I have no idea how these data shift if the lessons starts f.e at 8am. I found php function array_unshift, but actually do I need add some elements on the beginning? 
I need to shift the data if the start_time of the lessons is not equal to start_time(top row on the picture) 
[pict 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0MWN.png)

I did it with foreach loop and the array which represent timetable is:
`$timetable[$day]['lessons'][$z]['dividedlessons'][$q]['start_time']`

`$z` is index for individual lesson - on the pic 0,1,2,3,4; 
divided lessons mean when students have 2 different lesson in one lesson hour;
and `$q` is index for divided lesson; listofhours is 07:10, 08:00, 08:50,etc.

```
    Array ( [start_time] => 0000-00-00 08:00:00 [end_time] => 0000-00-00 08:45:00 [group] => [name] => BIO [room] => CP [lector] => Reh ) 
Array ( [start_time] => 0000-00-00 08:50:00 [end_time] => 0000-00-00 09:35:00 [group] => [name] => MAT [room] => CP [lector] => Ĺ af ) 
Array ( [start_time] => 0000-00-00 09:55:00 [end_time] => 0000-00-00 10:40:00 [group] => [name] => SLJ [room] => CP [lector] => Bal ) 
Array ( [start_time] => 0000-00-00 10:45:00 [end_time] => 0000-00-00 11:30:00 [group] => [name] => ANJ [room] => CP [lector] => Ĺ Ăˇn  
Array ( [start_time] => 0000-00-00 11:40:00 [end_time] => 0000-00-00 12:25:00 [group] => [name] => FYZ [room] => BF [lector] => Kis ) 
Array ( [start_time] => 0000-00-00 12:35:00 [end_time] => 0000-00-00 13:20:00 [group] => 1.sk [name] => INF [room] => AI [lector] => 
Haj )
Array ( [start_time] => 0000-00-00 12:35:00 [end_time] => 0000-00-00 13:20:00 [group] => ETV [name] => ETV [room] => CP [lector] => Cse ) 
Array ( [start_time] => 0000-00-00 13:30:00 [end_time] => 0000-00-00 14:15:00 [group] => 2.sk. [name] => INF [room] => AI [lector] => Haj ) 

Array ( [start_time] => 0000-00-00 08:00:00 [end_time] => 0000-00-00 08:45:00 [group] => [name] => ANJ [room] => CP [lector] => Ĺ Ăˇn ) 
Array ( [start_time] => 0000-00-00 08:50:00 [end_time] => 0000-00-00 09:35:00 [group] => [name] => MAT [room] => CP [lector] => Ĺ af ) 
Array ( [start_time] => 0000-00-00 09:55:00 [end_time] => 0000-00-00 10:40:00 [group] => [name] => DEJ [room] => CP [lector] => Str ) 
Array ( [start_time] => 0000-00-00 10:45:00 [end_time] => 0000-00-00 11:30:00 [group] => [name] => GEO [room] => CP [lector] => StK ) 
Array ( [start_time] => 0000-00-00 11:40:00 [end_time] => 0000-00-00 12:25:00 [group] => [name] => TSV [room] => T1 [lector] => Cse ) 
Array ( [start_time] => 0000-00-00 12:35:00 [end_time] => 0000-00-00 13:20:00 [group] => [name] => SLJ [room] => CP [lector] => Bal ) 

Array ( [start_time] => 0000-00-00 08:00:00 [end_time] => 0000-00-00 08:45:00 [group] => [name] => SLJ [room] => CP [lector] => Bal ) 
Array ( [start_time] => 0000-00-00 08:50:00 [end_time] => 0000-00-00 09:35:00 [group] => [name] => MAT [room] => CP [lector] => Ĺ af ) 
Array ( [start_time] => 0000-00-00 09:55:00 [end_time] => 0000-00-00 10:40:00 [group] => [name] => ANJ [room] => CP [lector] => Ĺ Ăˇn ) 
Array ( [start_time] => 0000-00-00 10:45:00 [end_time] => 0000-00-00 11:30:00 [group] => [name] => OBN [room] => CP [lector] => Kis )
Array ( [start_time] => 0000-00-00 11:40:00 [end_time] => 0000-00-00 12:25:00 [group] => [name] => VYV [room] => CP [lector] => Reh ) 
Array ( [start_time] => 0000-00-00 12:35:00 [end_time] => 0000-00-00 13:20:00 [group] => [name] => NEJ [room] => CP [lector] => Til ) 

Array ( [start_time] => 0000-00-00 08:00:00 [end_time] => 0000-00-00 08:45:00 [group] => [name] => ANJ [room] => CP [lector] => Ĺ Ăˇn ) 
Array ( [start_time] => 0000-00-00 08:50:00 [end_time] => 0000-00-00 09:35:00 [group] => [name] => TSV [room] => T1 [lector] => Cse ) 
Array ( [start_time] => 0000-00-00 09:55:00 [end_time] => 0000-00-00 10:40:00 [group] => [name] => MAT [room] => CP [lector] => Ĺ af )
Array ( [start_time] => 0000-00-00 10:45:00 [end_time] => 0000-00-00 11:30:00 [group] => [name] => SLJ [room] => CP [lector] => Bal ) 
Array ( [start_time] => 0000-00-00 11:40:00 [end_time] => 0000-00-00 12:25:00 [group] => [name] => CHE [room] => CP [lector] => Ĺ af ) 
Array ( [start_time] => 0000-00-00 12:35:00 [end_time] => 0000-00-00 13:20:00 [group] => NAV [name] => NAV [room] => [lector] => Kub ) 

Array ( [start_time] => 0000-00-00 08:00:00 [end_time] => 0000-00-00 08:45:00 [group] => [name] => MAT [room] => CP [lector] => Ĺ af ) 
Array ( [start_time] => 0000-00-00 08:50:00 [end_time] => 0000-00-00 09:35:00 [group] => [name] => SLJ [room] => CP [lector] => Bal ) 
Array ( [start_time] => 0000-00-00 09:55:00 [end_time] => 0000-00-00 10:40:00 [group] => [name] => TSV [room] => T1 [lector] => Cse ) 
Array ( [start_time] => 0000-00-00 10:45:00 [end_time] => 0000-00-00 11:30:00 [group] => [name] => BIO [room] => CP [lector] => Reh ) 
Array ( [start_time] => 0000-00-00 11:40:00 [end_time] => 0000-00-00 12:25:00 [group] => [name] => CHE [room] => CP [lector] => Til ) 
Array ( [start_time] => 0000-00-00 12:35:00 [end_time] => 0000-00-00 13:20:00 [group] => [name] => HUV [room] => CP [lector] => Bal )
```

'skratka' is abbrevation for days; 'hodiny' is lessons and 'delenehodiny' is dividedlesson..

[DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgP8H.png)

I tried explain it clearly I hope you will understand :) Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It would help us understand your structure and desired output better if you edit above to include the output from `print_r($timetable);` (copied from the browser page source, so linebreaks &  indentation are intact), and together with that, post an example of what the end result of your `$timetable` array structure is expected to be in a similar format to `print_r()`.

Comment: Please edit the original post above to include the print_r rather than posting it in comments. Instead of the deeply nested values though, please show the print_r for the entire `$timetable` array variable: `print_r($timetable);` It is important that the community understand its full structure rather than make inferences about it.

Comment: Did u mean this input, right?

Comment: No, I literally mean just `print_r($timetable);` _before_ the loop to display the full array structure, and use the [edit link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34427350/edit) instead of the comment thread to share new code or information.

Comment: There are a lot of data and the output is very strange how I see... Could I write you some pm please?

Comment: There is no PM mechanism and I don't accept them offsite. But if you copy the print_r from the browser page source, it will be well formatted and easy to read. You may then copy only a small section instead of all of it.

Comment: `Im trying it by this way, but it doesnt working... :(    ---                                                if (!empty($rozvrh[$p]['hodiny'][$z]['delenehodiny'])) {

         if ($rozvrh[$p]['hodiny'][$z]['delenehodiny'][$q]['start_time'] ==  $zoznam_hodin[$f]['start_time']) {           
        
           $z++;
           $f++;
      } else {

       $prvnihodina=$rozvrh[$p]['hodiny'][0]['delenehodiny'][$q]['start_time'];
       $prvnihodina=0;
       $z++;
       $f++;     
      }
  }`

Comment: Can you please show the structure and sample data of your database table.? what I understood is you want to sort the data according to that picture.

Comment: I added new picture. This is timetable now(all lessons start at 7.10, but it isnt correct) because all lessons start at 8am in this class. There are some lessons which start at 7.10 in other classes. And I would like to "assign" lessons to correct time.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. What I understood from that picture is that you want to sort those data according to the start time field in the data base. If that is the case you could just use `ORDER BY start_time ASC` from the Mysql. Also do not use date time if you are not using date. Use time instead. If this is not the case please do a pm. Will try to help.

Comment: Pls, where can I write you pm? Im new here :)))